# Non-blocking getch(), ncurses

Tags: linux, g++, blocking, ncurses, getch

I'm having some problems getting ncurses' getch() to block. Default operation seems to be non-blocking (or have I missed some initialization)? I would like it to work like getch() in Windows. I have tried various versions of

```
timeout(3000000);
nocbreak();
cbreak();
noraw();
etc...
```

(not all at the same time). I would prefer to not (explicitly) use any `WINDOW`, if possible. A `while` loop around getch(), checking for a specific return value is OK too.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The curses library is a package deal.  You can't just pull out one routine and hope for the best without properly initializing the library.   Here's a code that correctly blocks on `getch()`:

```
#include <curses.h>

int main(void) {
  initscr();
  timeout(-1);
  int c = getch();
  endwin();
  printf ("%d %c\n", c, c);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

From [a man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/curs_inopts/) (emphasis added):

> The `timeout` and `wtimeout` routines set blocking or non-blocking read for
>   a  given  window. **If `delay` is negative, blocking read is used (i.e.,
>   waits indefinitely for input).**

Comment: #include <ncurses.h>
    void main()
    {
      timeout(-3000000);
      getch();
    }
does not block for me. Any clues?

Comment: It's assumed that you're using the rest of curses properly, including initialization.

Comment: @JonasByström Of course the fact you declared main() void is, last I knew, undefined, which means the entire state of the program is not to be trusted. If nothing else though it's broken whether or not it appears to work (I say 'last I knew' but really I mean I’m uncertain off hand at this moment if it's by way of making it undefined but either way it's broken code).

Comment: @Pryftan Ever since the dawn of time, all of the following were legal C main prototypes: `void main(void), int main(void), int main(int argc, const char* argv[]), int main(int argc, const char* argv[], char* envp[])`. Just because you don't know about it does not make it undefined ;)

Answer (score 10):

You need to call `initscr()` or `newterm()` to initialize curses before it will work. This works fine for me:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main() {
    WINDOW *w;
    char c;

    w = initscr();
    timeout(3000);
    c = getch();
    endwin();

    printf("received %c (%d)\n", c, (int) c);
}
```