# How to get the last key pressed without stopping the C program?

Tags: c, linux, command-line, interface, user-input

Writing an application with command line interface and I would like to know at any time if F1 or ESC or an arrow key is pressed. What is the simplest way of doing this? I would like to avoid using a readline type library.

This is a Linux specific question; the program is not multithreaded.

Comment: This is platform specific- what platform(s) are you interested in supporting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An implementation of kbhit() for Linux is presented in [Beginning Linux Programming](http://www.scribd.com/doc/20555781/Beginning-Linux-Programming) page 167. You can read it on-line at the link provided.

EDIT: I mention kbhit() because it was posted as a solution before it was made clear that the question related to Linux. Unfortunately the solution has been deleted, which is unfortunate. The principle is that when kbhit() returns non-zero, a subsequent blocking *character-oriented* read call will not block. This is only true for character oriented input; getchar() and other standard functions that read stdio are typically *line-oriented*, so block until newline.

Comment: Then you misunderstand the code! kbhit() id non-blocking, and peeks the buffer to see if there is a character available, when it returns non-zero, a subsequent blocking read is then guaranteed *not* to block. Unfortunately the post showing how kbhit() is used (and which I was referring to) has been deleted, presumably because it was not intended for Linux. IMO it should be undeleted, it is still relevant.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to do this in the C standard, but C implementations on various operating systems usually have some extension to do this.

On Windows, you can use getch(). On Linux and Unix, look at this question:

[Non-blocking getch(), ncurses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905060/non-blocking-getch-ncurses)

Also, this is the very first question in the "System Dependencies" section in the C FAQ list:

[19.1](http://c-faq.com/osdep/cbreak.html)

Comment: I don't think that's correct. I suppose you can always do so by writing your own interrupt handlers.

Comment: Alex: There is no way in the C standard to get key presses to start sending signals, so you can't write a signal handler to do this. Perhaps you are thinking about how to do it in some specific operating system, such as Windows? But as I said, there is nothing in the C standard about it.

Comment: @Alex Xander: It sounds like you're writing an application level program instead of a device driver, so interrupt handlers are not generally available as an option.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple threads?

Comment: If you just want to check if a key is pressed, an extra thread would be overkill and complicate things unnecessarily.