# Implementing getch() functionality by using either fgets() or scanf()

Tags: c, scanf, fgets, getch

I am trying to write a program in C where I intend to control the execution of a while loop according to user input in stdin. I am able to write the program in three different ways as following which perform as intended:

### Using scanf() function

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
 char loop= 'y';
 while(loop=='y')
    {
     printf("Do you want to continue? [y|n]: ");
     scanf("%c", &loop);

     while(getchar() != '\n');
     if(loop != 'y' && loop != 'n')
        {
         printf("Error! Please enter 'y' or 'n' \n");
         loop = 'y';
        }
    }
 return 0;
}
```

---

### Using fgets() function

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
 char loop[5]= "yes\n";

 printf("%s",loop);
 while(strcmp(loop,"yes\n")==0)
    {
     printf("Do you want to continue? [yes|no]: ");
     if(strcmp(loop,"yes\n")!=0 && strcmp(loop,"no\n")!=0)
        printf("Error! Please Enter 'yes' or 'no'\n");
     else
        fgets(loop,5,stdin);
    }
 return 0;
}
```

---

### Using getch() from conio.h

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
 char loop= 'y';
 while(loop=='y')
    {
     printf("Do you want to continue? [y|n]: ");

     loop = getch();
     printf("\n");
     if(loop != 'y' && loop != 'n')
        {
         printf("Error! Please enter 'y' or 'n' \n");
         loop = 'y';
        }
    }
 return 0;
}
```

Although all the aforementioned methods perform the task of stopping or continuing the `while` loop according to user input, the `getch()` is little different. Using `getch()`, the user does not have to press the enter after the user inputs `y` or `n` and the program terminates or continues as soon as the user provides input.

---

I am aware that `conio.h` is not included in the standard gcc library and is frowned upon to use. However, I would like to implement the functionality of `getch()` using either `scanf()` or `fgets()` or any other standard library function. By functionality of `getch()`, I mean that as soon as a user press the desired key on terminal, the `while` loop should terminate without needing to press the enter by the user.

Is it possible for either `fgets()` or `scanf()` to do this task?

Comment: Short story: You can't, because the `getch` function bypasses `stdio` and reads more directly from the console. Long story: You can disable buffering on `stdin` which *might* help solve your problem (and then I recommend using [`getc` or `fgetc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) instead). No guarantees though.

Comment: BTW The `fgets` version is incorrect.

Comment: Oh, and you should *really* do some error checking for the input functions. All the functions mentioned (by you and me) all have return values that should be checked for errors or other problems.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY what is wrong in fgets() version? In my system, it is giving the desired output.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the comment. I have indeed done some error checking in all the programs. Is that not enough?

Comment: What if the user presses the EOF sequence instead of writing anything? You never check for that.

Comment: 1) Can't compile `return0;`. 2) `if(strcmp(loop,"yes\n")==0 && strcmp(loop,"no\n")==0)` is meaningless. Specifically, the loop can not be ended with `no`.

Comment: `if(strcmp(loop,"yes\n")==0 && strcmp(loop,"no\n")==0)`???

Comment: `if(strcmp(loop,"yes\n")==0 && strcmp(loop,"no\n")==0)` - This is to force the user to enter either 'yes' or 'no' otherwise report an error.

Comment: You do not understand what you are talking about.

Comment: @DavidBowling Yes, I do know it. But I agree with others that fgets() version is wrong. I am now trying to fix it. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: @DavidBowling I have now edited the fgets() version of the code. It now works correctly though I should have included the error checking.

Comment: Guys, now that from the discussion in the comments, it is clear that getch() cannot be implemented via `scanf()` or `fgets()` though some easy means, do you suggest that I should rollback this question? I guess that it might not be useful for any one. Please respond.

Comment: @Pankaj _It now works correctly_ no. It is still not correct. Try Enter `end`.

Comment: Code still is not quite behaving as expected; try to enter "maybe".

Comment: Even though the question itself is obvious for most people, there may be people who want to know it. You can post your conclusions as an answer yourself.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469139/what-is-equivalent-to-getch-getche-in-linux/; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pressed/; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513344/how-to-get-the-last-key-pressed-without-stopping-the-c-program; and no doubt many others.