# Immediately processing char instead of waiting for return key

Tags: c++, char

I want to accept several characters in my input and process them as they are being typed. I would use it like that:

```
char c;
string line;
    
while((c = getchar() != '.')) 
    line += c;   

cout << line << endl;
```

The expected behavior would be to stop getting inputs as soon as a '.' char is typed, without the need for the return button to be pressed.

Comment: not in standard C++, which has no notion of a keyboars

Comment: How are you running your program? It might not be C++ that is waiting for the newline, but the shell instead

Comment: Caleth, I'm runnig via shell.

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be to use the [ncurses](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) library which allows you to open a graphic window of a terminal and to have getch() type functions but which does not block your program if you allow it before ([Stack exemple here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905060/non-blocking-getch-ncurses/)).
Then it is possible to constantly check if a '.' was pressed and performed N actions at the same time.
I hope I was able to help you !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).